# listview, no mostrar elementos si no tiene datos

Tags: android-studio

estoy realizando un programa sobre una base de datos de series, tengo una base el cual me guarda una serie de Edittext, como el nombre de la serie, capitulos, temporadas, etc, lo que quiero mostrar en un listview es el Nombre de la serie, la temporada por la que voy y capitulo por el que voy, el problema es que cuando cargo los datos en el listview, tambien me aparecen datos en blanco, es decir, si yo agrego a la base el nombre de la serie "pepe" (primary key en la base), temporada "1" y capitulo "2", en el listview me parece pepe TEMP 1  CAP 2, pero si guardo solo el nombre de la serie y no pongo nada en temporada y capitulo, en el listview me sale pepe TEMP   CAP, hay alguna forma de que no muestre el nombre de la serie en listview si solo guardo el nombre de la serie y no pongo nada en temporada y capitulo?

aqui esta el codigo que utilizo para estraer los datos de la base y mostrarlos en listview, la base contiene algunos campos(edittext) mas, pero solo quiero mostrar los que os comento, por eso el nombre de la serie es la fila 0, temporada es la fila 6 y capitulo la 7, podeis ayudarme?, gracias.

```
public void cargarvistos() {
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "series.db", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor fila = bd.rawQuery("select * from datos order by nombre asc", null);// muestra registros por numero ascendente
    int cantidad = fila.getCount();
    int i = 0;
    String[] listado = new String[cantidad];
    if (fila.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String linea = fila.getString(0)+"\n TEMP.  " + fila.getString(6)+ "  CAP.  " + fila.getString(7);
            listado[i] = linea;
            i++;
        } while (fila.moveToNext());
        bd.close();
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.color_blanco_listview1, listado);
    ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listavistos);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes optar por un if dentro del do-while, comprobando si la variable TEMP y CAP son nulas o no. Te propongo algo así:

```
do {
            String linea = fila.getString(0)+"\n";
            if (!fila.getString(6).equals("")) linea += "TEMP.  " + fila.getString(6);
            if (!fila.getString(7).equals("")) linea += "CAP.  " + fila.getString(7);
            listado[i] = linea;
            i++;
        } while (fila.moveToNext());
```

Comment: Ok lo probare en llegar a casa gracias!!